# Collapse Expand in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to expand and collapse the content in jquery. But the toggle responding reversely.
When I expanding, it is showing the content from bottom to top and when I collapsing, it is showing the content from top to bottom.
And also, when it is expanding, I want the image also to come right of the content. and when I collapsing, it should collapse and set it to top.

Before:

[image]

I need like this:

[image]

Here is what I tried.

```js
ons.bootstrap();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".header").click(function() {
    $(".content").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://components.onsen.io/onsen-css-components-default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://components.onsen.io/patterns/lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://components.onsen.io/patterns/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://components.onsen.io/patterns/lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ons-list-item style="min-height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">
  <div style="cursor:pointer; margin-left: 291px;" class="header">
    <ons-icon style="font-size: 23px; font-weight: bold; color: #000000; width: 1em" icon="ion-navicon" class="ons-icon ion-more ons-icon--ion ons-icon--fw fa-lg"></ons-icon>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 12px; margin-top: -15px; display: block;" class="content">
    <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: #666666;">Content 1<br>content 2</span> 
  </div>
</ons-list-item>
```

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle please?

Comment: I couldn't able to import the css from onsenui website. That's why posted the code.

Comment: You just make it an external resource, there's a panel for it :)

Comment: I hope this helps you. http://jqueryui.com/toggle/

Answer (score -1):

The .content div should start as display:none if you want to achieve that effect.